# Import multiple libraries in makefile within Javac command

Tags: java, makefile, escaping, javac

#### The problem

This is a problem I just faced using makefile in java, on Windows.
I wanted to set up my classpath with multiple path (libraries, etc.). The new command work by hands, but not from the makefile which throws me this error :

> javac : no source files

#### Example

Let's say I have this makefile :

```
JFLAGS = -g
JARFLAGS = -cvfm

CLASSPATH = ./bin
LIBS = C:/java/lib/mylib.jar

SOURCEPATH = ./src/client

compileAll:
    javac $(JFLAGS) -d $(CLASSPATH) -cp $(CLASSPATH)\;$(LIBS) $(SOURCEPATH )/*.java
    jar $(JARFLAGS) app.jar bin/client/MANIFEST.MF bin/client/*.class
```

So the command line to compile the project is :

```
javac -g -d ./bin -cp ./bin;C:/java/libs/lib.jar ./src/client/*.java
```

It works well.
The class files goes to ./bin directory. It imports classes from ./bin and the lib.jar library. And it compliles all the source files from the ./src/client directory.

This command works perfectly by hands, but no from the makefile which doesn't compile anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my text editor which colored the ';' character, I understood that I just needed to **escape (disable) the ';' character by using a '\'** :

```
javac -g -d ./bin -cp ./bin\;C:/java/libs/lib.jar ./src/client/*.java
```

Now, it works well from makefile !